# Can I insert millions of rows in one partition? (good load balancing not required)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I've designed a data access layer for a worker role, which will execute range queries and batch inserts on one Azure Table partition. This partition can potentially contains millions of row.

While this partition will only be consumed by a few workers only, with a reasonable access rate, and good performance is not a critical requirement, is there any problem doing so? Is there a limit on the size of the rowkey index?

Of course I have read [Real World: Designing a Scalable Partitioning Strategy for Windows Azure Table Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508997.aspx).

Comment: Not sure why there are votes to close this question, but this is a reasonable question to ask

Comment: loool good one @nathanchere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no stated limit on a size of a partition that I'm aware of.

Do know that there is a limit in number of operations per partition (500/sec) and that availability of storage is at the partition level (ie: if the partition goes down, everything inside it goes down)

Obviously batch inserts will be limited to no more than 100 entities at a time

Comment: looks like there's nothing to worry so far, Thanks for the answer.